# How to write an abstract class as an interface

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I've googled extensively for an answer to this question, but I either do not know what the technical term is, or else it's not possible, so forgive any ignorance on my part, please.

---

First the code, then the rationale behind why.

```
package package1;
public interface MyInterface {
    public ... method1(...);
    public ... method2(...);
    public ... method3(...);
    public ... method4(...);

    public static interface|class DEFAULT extends|implements MyInterface {
        public abstract ... method1(...);

        public ... method2(...) {
            // code
        }

        public ... method3(...) {
            // code
        }

        public abstract ... method4(...);
    }
}
```

Now normally I would abstract a class to implement `MyInterface`, but in this case, I cannot, as Java (understandably) does not support class inheritance from multiple classes (although interfaces can extend multiple other interfaces).

My (ideal) use case would be something along the lines of:

```
package package3;
import package1.MyInterface;
import package2.SomeBaseClass;
public class MyClass extends SomeBaseClass implements MyInterface.DEFAULT {
    // other class code

    public ... method1(...) {
        // code
    }

    public ... method4(...) {
        // code
    }
}
```

I could probably figure out some workaround, but I want to know if there is an easier/more elegant way to do this, before I spend a ton of time writing code that might end up being outclassed by something I hadn't thought of.

---

Edit: I should have specified that each of the classes/interfaces are from different packages (the above code has been modified to reflect this distinction). Basically I'm combining the functionality of two packages into a third.

---

Edit: I've come up with the following, which I believe follow the solutions\comments suggested of accomplishing this *by composition*.

```
package MyPackage;

import package1.SomeBaseClass;
import package2.MyInterface;

public class MyClass extends SomeBaseClass {
    private .. someVariable;

    private MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface.DEFAULT() {
        public ... method1(...) {
            // do something with someVariable
        }

        public ... method4(...) {
            // code
        }
    };

    public void doSomethingThatRequiresMyInterface() {
        myInterface.method1(...);
    }
}
```

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Are you using Java 8? If so, google for "default methods". If not, what you want is impossible.

Comment: In your question you don't explain why not simply use as `abstract` class, why do you need the combination of abstract class & interface.

Comment: @alfasin I thought the provided ideal use case showed that.

Comment: @JBNizet Java 7, though an upgrade could be useful, but there's the issues with compatibility for older versions.

Comment: @radar33 I don't understand the use-case: why not put all the methods in an abstract class, implement whatever you want and then extend that class with your `MyClass` (and implement there the abstract methods) ? what's the added-value of an additional interface ?

Comment: Java 7 doesn't allow methods of interfaces to have an implementation. So you can't implement DEFAULT as an interface. But it also doesn't allow inheriting from two different classes. So it's impossible. Java 8 allows interfaces to have default methods, which provide an implementation (but still may not have state). So Java 8 default methods *could* be the answer. But my guess is that you should use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: @alfasin I hope I've edited the question to better explain the need for the interface. If not, I try explain it better.

Comment: @radar33 I have the feeling that you're confusing two different things. As you wrote, you can implement as many interfaces as you want so that's not an issue. The issue is that you'd like, if I understand correctly, to inherit methods from different classes (abstract or not) and you can't do that because you're limited to inherit only one class. Is that correct?

Comment: @alfasin I believe so, yes, but let me see if I can explain further. I'd like to use something like user3465651's answer (or Java 8's default methods), and while I'm writing the code for all three packages, I'd rather not make package1 (co-)dependent on package2, if that makes sense.

Comment: Even with user3465651's solution you'll remain with the same problem: you can't extend two classes! The only possible solution (that doesn't use Java 8) was suggested by JB Nizet in one of the comments above: use composition.

Comment: That solution _is_ pure and simple inheritance, though. I'll take a look at composition.

Comment: Updated question with what I believe is code for a composition. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using/can use Java 8 'default methods' might be what you are looking for -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

However, I don't think you are far off from what you want to achieve with the code listed above.

MyInterface.java

```
    public interface MyInterface {
        public ... method1(...);
        public ... method2(...);
        public ... method3(...);
        public ... method4(...);
    }
```

Default.java

```
public abstract class Default implements MyInterface {
    public abstract ... method1(...);

    public ... method2(...) {
        // code
    }

    public ... method3(...) {
        // code
    }

    public abstract ... method4(...);
}
```

SomeBaseClass.java

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass extends Default {
    public void someNewMethod();
}
```

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass extends SomeBaseClass {
    // other class code

    @Override
    public ... method1(...) {
        // code
    }

    @Override
    public ... method4(...) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to include import package information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements well, I think the new default methods (also known as defender methods) that were introduced in Java 8 could help you ([tutorial at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)).

They allow to define a default behaviour for interface methods, so that classes implementing them don't have to duplicate this default behaviour if it is sufficient.

It was introduced mainly so that the Java developement team could add new methods to API interfaces without breaking existing code implementing these interfaces.

Example :

Interface :

```
public interface MyInterface {
    default void method1(String arg1, Object arg2){
        //code...
    }

    default String method2(){
        //code...
    }

    String method3();
}
```

Implementation class :

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    private String field1;

    public String method3(){
        //code...
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(){
        //code...
    }
}
```

In this case, the implementation class doesn't implement the interface's methods marked as default, so they still can be called and the default implementation will be used. However it still has to implement the `method3` that has no default implementatio in the interface.

There are limitations and caveats though, a few of which are listed in [this blog article](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/04/04/java-8-friday-the-dark-side-of-java-8/), so be careful.

As an aside : you don't have to specify the "public" accessor for interfaces methods in Java since it is already the default,

Comment: I put the "public" accessor in the interfaces so I can do a straight copy-and-paste from the interface to the implementing class so I don't forget to specify the accessor, which makes it easier if I'm not using Eclipse while going through that particular coding session (which is often).

Answer (score 0):

You could use composition, where you would create a class that implements the interface, and provides the default functionality, and then pass an instance of the default implementation to the concrete class.  If the concrete class doesn't provide the functionality, call the version implemented by the default instance.

Interface:

```
public interface Foo {

    int method1(int a, String b);

    String method2(int a);

    String method3(String b);

}
```

Default Implementation:

```
public class DefaultFoo implements Foo {

    @Override
    public int method1(int a, String b) {
        return a + b.length();
    }

    @Override
    public String method2(int a) {
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public String method3(String b) {
        return b;
    }

}
```

Concrete Implementation:

```
public class GreenFoo implements Foo {

    Foo defaultFoo = new DefaultFoo();

    @Override
    public int method1(int a, String b) {
        return "Green " + a + ", Mean" + b;
    }

    @Override
    public int method2(int a) {
        return a*a;
    }

    @Override
    public int method3(Sting b) {
        // I don't want to implement this, so I just call the default.
        return defaultFoo.method3(b);
    }

}
```